# buffer time very slow in RED5 server

Tags: actionscript, red5

I have a video player and I use red5 server

in the actionscript code i wrote the buffertime to 5

but its too long until he buffer it.

How can i fix that?

Is the red5 server is too slow?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the buffertime to 5 seconds is quite strange.
But it depends on the usage scenario. Are you doing LiveStreaming or VOD?

If the buffer takes too long to fill, that means the internet connection you are using might be too slow to fill the buffer in the appropriate time.

How long does it exactly take in milliseconds untill the video starts to play?
You should monitor and trace also the other variables given in the ActionScript3 docs:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#bufferLength

And then as the AS3 docs also suggest: You can calculate the time the buffer needs to fill up.
And you could measure this time/ratio from different clients in different networks/locations to get a feeling for that.

Sebastian